# Examples of Polycyclic Group

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading about polycyclic groups recently.
Could anyone please give me some example of polycyclic groups?

Comment: All finitely generated abelian groups and nilpotent groups are polycyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finitely generated nilpotent groups are polycyclic. This gives many examples. However, not every finitely generated solvable group is polycyclic. A well-known counterexamples is the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,2)$.
The following result also may give some idea about polycyclic groups. Philip Hall conjectured, and Louis Auslander proved that every polycyclic group can be faithfully embedded into the integer unimodular group $SL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ for some $n$. Conversely Anatoly Maltsev proved that solvable subgroups of $GL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ are polycyclic.

Explicit examples: All dihedral groups $D_n$ with $n=2^k$ and the infinite dihedral group $D_{\infty}$.